# ASP.net CRUD WCF AJAX Post call Method not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, wcf

Hey all I am trying to figure out why my GET works just fine but my POST does not seem to work.

[image]

My web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                           Initial Catalog=master;
                           Persist Security Info=True;
                           User ID=xx;
                           Password=xx"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <clear />
      <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" type="" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="xamlx-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.xamlx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="xamlx-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.xamlx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="xamlx-Integrated-4.0" path="*.xamlx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Xaml.Hosting.XamlHttpHandlerFactory, System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor=""
      resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="rules-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.rules" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="rules-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.rules" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="rules-Integrated-4.0" path="*.rules" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler"
      scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="xoml-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.xoml" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="xoml-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.xoml" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="xoml-Integrated-4.0" path="*.xoml" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler"
      scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor=""
      resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="ISAPI-dll" path="*.dll" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"
      allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"
      allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.rem" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"
      allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-soap-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.soap" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"
      allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="aspq-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.aspq" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
      responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="cshtm-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.cshtm" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="cshtml-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.cshtml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="vbhtm-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.vbhtm" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="vbhtml-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.vbhtml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="TraceHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="trace.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="WebAdminHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="WebAdmin.axd" verb="GET,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.WebAdminHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="AssemblyResourceLoader-Integrated-4.0" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler"
      scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-Integrated-4.0" path="*.rem" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandlerFactory, System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-soap-Integrated-4.0" path="*.soap" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandlerFactory, System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="aspq-Integrated-4.0" path="*.aspq" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="cshtm-Integrated-4.0" path="*.cshtm" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="cshtml-Integrated-4.0" path="*.cshtml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="vbhtm-Integrated-4.0" path="*.vbhtm" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="vbhtml-Integrated-4.0" path="*.vbhtml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
      responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices-Integrated-4.0" path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler"
      scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="ScriptResourceIntegrated-4.0" path="*ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler"
      scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"
      allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.rem" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"
      allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-soap-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.soap" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"
      allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="aspq-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.aspq" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
      responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="cshtm-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.cshtm" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="cshtml-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.cshtml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="vbhtm-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.vbhtm" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="vbhtml-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.vbhtml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="TRACEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="TRACE" type="" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false"
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Pragma, Cache-Control" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>    
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <system.codedom>

    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>

  </system.codedom>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GoogleChromeExt.apiAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>

    <services>
      <service name="GoogleChromeExt.api" 
               behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="GoogleChromeExt.apiAspNetAjaxBehavior" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="GoogleChromeExt.api"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

and my .svc.cs code:

```
namespace GoogleChromeExt
{
    public class ChromeExtData
    {
        public string fnum { get; set; }
        public string noty { get; set; }
        public string ffl { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string mname { get; set; }
        public string numsr { get; set; }
        public string sor { get; set; }
        public string pob { get; set; }
        public string sex { get; set; }
        public string birthday { get; set; }
        public string ethnicity { get; set; }
        public string race { get; set; }
        public string cstatus { get; set; }
        public string miscnumbers { get; set; }
        public string transp { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class api
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public void DoWork()
        {
            return;
        }

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method           = "GET",
                   UriTemplate      = "SAutomationOptions/getall",
                   ResponseFormat   = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   RequestFormat    = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   BodyStyle        = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        public async Task<ChromeExtData> getall()
        {
            ChromeExtData _chromeExtData = new ChromeExtData();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                _chromeExtData              = await conn.QuerySingleAsync<ChromeExtData>("SELECT * FROM SAutomationOptionsSSRCC", null);
            }

            return _chromeExtData;
        }

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
                   UriTemplate = "SAutomationOptions/fnumber/{FNum}",
                   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        public async Task<ChromeExtData> FNum(String FNum)
        {
            ChromeExtData _chromeExtData = new ChromeExtData();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                _chromeExtData = await conn.QuerySingleAsync<ChromeExtData>(
                                            "SELECT * FROM SAutomationOptionsSSRCC WHERE fnum = @fNum", 
                                            new { fNum = FNum }
                                       );
            }

            return _chromeExtData;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I load the GET into the browser http://localhost:56784/api.svc/SAutomationOptions/getall:

```
{"birthday":"5\/21\/2019","code":"qTest","cstatus":"F","ethnicity":"Latino","ffl":"14774123","fname":"Bob","fnum":"5510471","lname":"Barker","miscnumbers":"645","mname":"Showcase","noty":"True","numsr":"514","pob":"TN","race":"American, Native Hawaiian","sex":"M","sor":"AZ","transp":"Redemption, Redemption of This"}
```

Which is what I am expecting it to be the output.

However, when I try to do the POST http://localhost:56784/api.svc/SAutomationOptions/fnumber/15263 I get:

[image]

Testing it with Ajax as well using this JS code:

```
function ajaxPostData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:56784/api.svc/SAutomationOptions/fnumber/15263',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({"FNum": 15263}),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        },
            failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error: ", jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

Brings back the error:

> POST http://localhost:56784/api.svc/SAutomationOptions/fnumber/15263 400 (Bad Request)
>
> statusText: "Bad Request"

I'm sure it has something to do with my Web.Config file but I just don't know what it could be?

Comment: First of all, the table you query in the database are two tables (I referred to your new post, SAutomationOptionsSSRCC,NicsAutomationOptionsSSRCC), and your GetAll returns only one object (its fnum=5510471), so how can you return another object in the same table (FNum=15263)

Comment: wish you have good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue but failed. On my side, the result could be returned properly.  I suspect there is something wrong with querying statement.  Are you sure that the request would have a proper response? I suggest you return a hard-code object to exclude this.
Besides,If this question has something to do with CORE, I suggest you remove the ContentType, or change it to below.

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.